# When does PHP call Write method on Session Handler Class?

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

I have this issue:

```
new MySqli  
new Session - with the mysqli as parameter  
$_SESSION Usage  
close MySqli
```

But at the end, after I close MySqli, `Session::_write` is called. Can anyone tell me how can I securely close my MySqli connection after everything is done? Or I don't actually need to? I was thinking that every time the page is accessed a new MySqli connection is opened and never closed, which brings me to thinking I might get some kind of overflow sometime. Any Information would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP parser is only running when there is a script to process. How does it know when a script needs to be processed? Your web server sends them to it and outputs its data via http to the client. Every time the php process ends (end of script) it disconnects from the sql server, unless you've specified it to leave the connection open.

I would not be worried about it leaving the connection open due to the last Session::_write call, though I would call Session::write_close before closing the SQL connection if you are using it for sessions just to be safe and make sure all data is written back to the db.

Comment: write_close solved everything. I'd + but I'm new in here, thank you mate!